# ¿Cómo validar un spinner en android?

Tags: java, android, spinner

mi problema es el siguiente.
Tengo un spinner en android studio ya lo poblé con datos de mysql los datos que contiene son bandera y nombre de países, lo que quiero saber es como hacer para que el usuario tenga que escoger un país antes de guardar los datos.

```
 //validamos el campo spinner lista de pais
public void validarSpinnerPais(Spinner campo){

    View selectedView = campo.getSelectedView();
    if (selectedView != null && selectedView instanceof TextView) {
        TextView selectedTextView = (TextView) selectedView;
        selectedTextView.setError("Selecciona pais");
    }

}
```

Comment: Puedes crear un `String` para guardar el dato del `Spinner` en el evento que se encarga de escuchar si se seleccionó un dato, luego verificas si ese `String` esta vació, y si lo está, entonces no se procederá a guardar el dato.

Comment: Para incluir el código que pusiste en el comentario debes darle al botón de [edit]

Comment: Si el método que usted me dice funciona perfectamente cundo lleno es spinner con un array, el problema se da  es con el espinner países llenado desde la base de datos. no toma o no reconoce ningún elemento.

Comment: Podrías publicar todo el código?

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el método getSelectedItem(), que te devuelve lo seleccionado en el Spinner. Sería algo parecido a esto:

```
//Si el spinner es diferente de vacío
if (campo.getSelectedItem()!=""){
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Algo seleccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

//Si el spinner no tiene nada seleccionado   
}else{
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Nada selecccionado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el primer elemento de la lista sea la palabra **seleccione**, seria el elemento en la posición cero de la lista:

```
 if(campo.getSelectedItemPosition()==0){
        TextView errorText=(TextView)campo.getSelectedView();
        errorText.setError("");
        errorText.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
        errorText.setText("Seleccione un pais");
 }
```

Si la posición seleccionada es la cero entonces que se le setee un mensaje de error en el `spinner`.